# Are some steps wrong in this derivation (Kronig Penney Model)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice#Kronig.E2.80.93Penney_model), Wikipedia has the derivation for the equation:

> $$\cos(ka)=\cos(\alpha a) + P \frac{\sin(\alpha a)}{\alpha a}$$

I didn't understand one of the steps:
[image]

$\beta^2-\alpha^2$ should be equal to $\frac{2m(V_o-2|E|)}{\hbar^2}$ and not $\frac{2m(V_o)}{\hbar^2}$. I don't understand how they managed to come up with $P=\frac{mV_o ba}{\hbar^2}$. Am I missing something?

---

Also, my textbook states that if $V_0=0$, then $\alpha=k$, and thus $E=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}$. I don't see how that is true. What we get when $V_0=0$ is $\cos(k a)=\cos(\alpha a)$. That implies $\alpha a = 2n\pi \pm k a$ and not $\alpha=k$. Is my book being hand-wavy?

---

Comment: For the first question : $E$ is finite, even in the limit $=V_0\to\infty$, so it can be neglected. For the second question : we are interested in the lowest energy state, which is the one with $n=0$.

Comment: @Adam Got it. Could you answer the second part of the question too ?

Comment: I've edited my first comment.

Comment: @Adam Why are we interested only in the lowest energy state? I was thinking along the lines of " free electrons (i.e. when $V_0=0$) are not *quantized* "...

Comment: My answer for the second question might not be right (I would need to redo the derivation to be sure, to understand the relationship between $k$ and $\alpha$). But note that we are imposing periodic conditions (with period $a$) , even in the free case, which will quantify the energy.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you redo the derivation and let me know. @Adam